# Get Parent with multiple children in desc order

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I get `Parent` with multiple `Children` in `desc` order in SQL Server to show the newly created `Parent` with its `Children` at the top in a list?

```sql
SELECT CRMEvents.ID, ISNULL(CRMEvents.ParentEventId, '') as Parent
FROM CRMEvents
WHERE partyid = 4133
ORDER BY ISNULL(CRMEvents.ParentEventID, CRMEvents.ID), CRMEvents.CreatedOn
```

[image]

---

I need to get in desc order as Parent1 with its children, parent2 with its children and so on..

Comment: Don't put image's here... (unless they REALLY make thing clearer, which is not the case in this situation...)

Comment: With my previous comment I did mean to say that this link is much clearer: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ee0b60274929e9f9bf7438114ffe2b36

Comment: That looks good! but do you know the solution to my problem. please give me a solution

Comment: You want items ordered, but it's unclear what the link is between `id` and `Parentx`, and if I get the description right you want to sort by `Parentx` ?

Comment: A parent can have one or more children, and similarly, a child can also have one or more sub children. So I want the latest Parent with its children at the top

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c3468/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE myproblem (
   id int,
   parent int);

INSERT INTO myproblem values (5098,0),(5099,5098),(5100,5099),(5101,5099);
INSERT INTO myproblem values (5102,0),(5107,5102);
INSERT INTO myproblem values (5106,0),(5108,5106),(5110,5106);
INSERT INTO myproblem values (5109,0),(5111,5109);
INSERT INTO myproblem values (5112,0);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ParentUserType.Id As Parent ,count(ChildUserType.Id) AS 'Number of children'
    FROM myproblem AS ChildUserType
    LEFT JOIN myproblem AS ParentUserType ON ChildUserType.Parent = ParentUserType.Id
    GROUP BY ParentUserType.Id
    ORDER BY COUNT(ChildUserType.Id)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c3468/1/0)**:

```
| Parent | Number of children |
|--------|--------------------|
|   5098 |                  1 |
|   5102 |                  1 |
|   5109 |                  1 |
|   5106 |                  2 |
|   5099 |                  2 |
| (null) |                  5 |
```